# jpa mssql @Lob and create 2GB columns with portability

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

I would like to create BLOB field in application tables usign JPA. I have to support multiple databases (Derby, Microsoft SQL Server). When I define @Lob fields as:

```
@Lob
private byte[] fileData;
```

JPA creates default size of BLOB fields regarding each RDBMS. In MSSQL i have FILEDATA BLOB with default size 8000 bytes. Which is not enough. When I define the definition as:

```
@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition = "varbinary(max)")
private byte[] fileData;
```

I lost portability. JPA cannot create varbinary column of type VARBINARY in Derby DB. When I use following definition:

```
@Lob
@Column(length = 2147483647)
private byte[] fileData;
```

MSSQL report problem with table creation, because "The size (2147483647) given to the column 'FILEDATA' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000)."

What is a best solution for creating BLOB fields with portability in mind and provide specific BLOB size as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option may be not to use column definitions at all. Two approaches:

1. Maintain different SQL create scripts - one for each target database type.
2. Use a database evolution tool such as http://liquibase.org which will maintain your database schema and which is known to be database independent as far as possible.

I'm a very happy Liquibase user. It saves a lot of time and reduces SQL-pain once it is set up. But one disadvantage: As there is no JPA-Liquibase integration at the moment, you have to keep you entity classes and the liquibase changeset in sync manually.

There are other such tools (e.g. http://flywaydb.org/) but I don't know how database independent they are.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using liquibase but wanted to omit separating jpa and liquibase schema definition and sync it manually. I see that only option in this situation is to: a) disable jpa auto creation, b) create liquibase schema creation scripts from scratch and keep it synchronized during database schema changes.